# force php-fpm to release memory

Tags: php, fpm

i have this config for my php-fpm

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5900
pm.start_servers = 200
pm.min_spare_servers = 200
pm.max_spare_servers = 3900
pm.process_idle_timeout = 2s;
pm.max_requests = 6800
```

my php version is 7.4 and i use centos 7 64bit
i have no problem normally but when one user import one excel with 200000 record and i import that on mysql my problem start.
php use too many memory for do this work and finally it done and use 10G memory and after this work php-fpm not release that 10G memory and i should reload or restart my php-fpm
why php-fpm not release memory after that job done?
can i do some work manually to fix this issue?

Comment: I suspect your volume of dynamic components are much higher than necessary. 
--------- 
How much RAM is on the server?  Number of cores/cpu's?  
After your import has completed, pleaase run the following query and post the TEXT results here.
-------------    
Supporting query to SUM all Sleeping MEMORY_USED and MAX_MEMORY_USED that could be orphaned until stop/start instance.
-----------------    
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command = "Sleep"\G;

Comment: You can enforce the GC (garbage collector) to run. BUT, there should be no need for that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles